# React-redux action is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to call an API with redux action
but everytime I call it in my componentDidMount function, it gives me an error stating that my function is not defined.. i'm so confused, I've been using my past redux project as reference and it's using the same method but it works.

Have a look at my codes

**Reducer**

```js
import * as types from '../actions/actionconst';

const initialState = {
  isfetching: false,
  categories: [],
  error: null
}
const categoryReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case types.FETCH_CATEGORIES:
    console.log('in fetch categories');
    state = {
      ...state,
      isfetching: true,
      categories: action.payload
    }
    break;
    case types.FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
    state ={...state, categories: action.payload, isfetching: false}
    break;

    case types.FETCH_CATEGORIES_ERROR:
    state = {...state, isfetching: false, error: action.payload}
  }
  return state;
}

export default categoryReducer
```

**Action**

```js
import * as types from './actionconst';
import categoryAPI from '../api/categoryAPI';

export function getCategory(){

  return {dispatch => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/categories")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      dispatch({
        type: types.FETCH_CATEGORIES
        payload: responseData
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({type: types.FETCH_CATEGORIES_ERROR, payload: err});
    })
  }}
}
```

**Container**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import Category from '../components/category';

class CategoryContainer extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log('category props', this.props);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('masuk CDM');
    this.props.fetchCategory()
  }

  render(){
    var viewtypequery = window.innerWidth >= 1025 ? "computers" : "mobile"
    return(
      <Category alphabets={this.state.alph}
        categorylist={this.state.categoriestemp}
        view={viewtypequery}
        active={this.state.isActive}
      />
    )
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state is', state);
  return{
    categories: state.category
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
      fetchCategory: () => {
        console.log('cuk ta');
        dispatch(getCategory())
      }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CategoryContainer)
```

I dont know if I miss something, It's been a while since I touch this project, been rewatching redux tutorial but I still couldn't find any solutions..

Comment: What is the exact error message? Which function is not defined?

Comment: @AnthonyKong this is the error message: `index.js:8181 Uncaught ReferenceError: getCategory is not defined
    at Object.fetchCategory (index.js:8181)
    at CategoryContainer.componentDidMount (index.js:8154)
    at index.js:31883
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (index.js:31693)
    at index.js:31882
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (index.js:13487)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (index.js:36788)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (index.js:7191)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (index.js:7138)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (index.js:14399)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see you importing your getCategory action in your component. I would generally write it like that:

```
import { getCategory } from '../path-to-action';
.......

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getCategory})(CategoryContainer)
```

and then use it directly in the componentDidMount lifecycle method:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getCategory()
  }
```

Comment: I'll try this solution, the reason why i dont import the action is because I had it on my mapDispatchToProps, and from what I understand, it should automatically called the action that I need(?) **EDIT** my bad, after re-reading my old codes, I actually import my actions.. I'll try importing the action then i'll see what happened. Sorry :\

Comment: Okay problem solved, thank you, it was a stupid mistake on my part, Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: With the solution I provided, you don't need a mapDispatchToProps. If you want to pass a mapDispatch to props you would need to use bindActionCreators from redux. In your case I don't think it's needed.

Comment: I spent an hour trying to figure this one out, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Arga try to use bindActionCreators from redux. Make changes in your code to

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import Category from '../components/category';
import CategoryActions from '../actions/category'; // notice this will be your category actions file

class CategoryContainer extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log('category props', this.props);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('masuk CDM');
    this.props.getCategory(); // change here we call function from props binded to category component, this function is defined in your actions file
  }

  render(){
    var viewtypequery = window.innerWidth >= 1025 ? "computers" : "mobile"
    return(
      <Category alphabets={this.state.alph}
        categorylist={this.state.categoriestemp}
        view={viewtypequery}
        active={this.state.isActive}
      />
    )
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state is', state);
  return{
    categories: state.category
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators(CategoryActions, dispatch) // notice change here we use bindActionCreators from redux to bind our actions to the component
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CategoryContainer)
```

Hopefully it helps.